# What does the tests of "scale" check?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I have found this test: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/mood.test.html

unfortunately I didn't find any information on wikipedia, but what "scale" means? What do those tests check?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They test equality of distributions, and are sensitive to departures where the distribution in one group is a scaled version of the distribution in the other. There's [more here](http://www.stat.ucl.ac.be/ISdidactique/Rhelp/library/ctest/html/mood.test.html), including the caveat that there are better tests than Mood's.

Comment: excuse me, what tests are better then mood ?

Comment: there are [some mentioned here](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.aoms/1177704370)